# Get data from subscribe function in local variable angular 6

Tags: angular

This is my api call using post in my app.service.ts

```
userinsert(user:User,cart:Cart[])
{

    var databaseinput={user:user,cart:cart};
  return  this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/payment",databaseinput);

}
```

and this is my cart.component.ts
I am using subscribe here to get data like this

```
export class CartComponent{
    mydata:string;
myfuncto(){
    this.appservice.userinsert(user,currentcart).subscribe(
      data => {this.mydata=data// want to do something like this
      },
      error => { console.log(error); // Error if any
      },
      ()=> {}

    )
console.log(mydata) //it should print the data
}
}
```

But it gives me error type object is not assignable to type string ,I used data.json() but no success ,any idea how to do it??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the response is an Object, change your mydata variable to a type of Object or any

```
mydata:any;
```

also console.log should be inside the subscribe since the request is asynchronous, otherwise it will be undefined.

Comment: how to use it in outside function??

Comment: you need to have another function and pass the value to the function inside the subscribe. mark if this helped